# 2 proc print output in the same page (listing or rtf)

Tags: sas

I am running two proc print and would like to compare them visually on the SAS listing output. Both proc print prints only 3 observations.

The issue is I can't have the 2 output in one and  same page...I have to scroll down for one page to another page to look at the other output.  I have tried option pagesize=MAX but it doesn't work (MIN neither)...Is there a way to achieve what I want ?

I was wondering if an ODS statement redirecting to RTF or (PDF) would do that ?

Thanks in advance

sas_kappel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both ODS destinations can give you this, using the `startpage=never` option, which tells SAS not to start a new page when a new procedure is run.
These output to a results window, rather than the listing output.

```
option obs=3;
ods pdf startpage=never;
proc print data=sashelp.class;
run;
proc print data=sashelp.class;
run;
ods pdf close;
option obs=max;
```

Answer (score 1):

For the listing destination, you can replace the pagebreak with another character (e.g. a space) by using the option: `option formdlim=' ';`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Keith.

And would it be possible to have it directly in my output sas window ? I was thinking the ods statement ( as I only need the listing output) It  doesn't seems to work:

```
option startpage=never obs=3;
proc print data=sashelp.class;
run;
proc print data=sashelp.class;
run;
option obs=max;
```

So I guess there is no other option to achieving this other than ODS statement ?